# How do I check the bonus for a complete armour set?

Tags: dragon-age-2

I'm playing as a rogue and have obtained, and am wearing, the entire "Last Descent" armour set, which as per the descriptions on each item has a `bonus for complete item set`.

This is great, but what *is* the bonus? Without knowing this I can't reach a solid decision on when to stop wearing the set and swap out better (but probably non-setted) armour...

From some testing (putting bits of armour back on and off) I have determined that the set bonus in this case is *probably* +20 health and +10 attack, but it would be useful to know if there is somewhere in-game where I can see the given bonus for any set of armour I've managed to collect.

Comment: Only way I know of is to check http://dragonage.wikia.com and hope the stats for the items are up. Doesn't appear to be true in this case.

Comment: Opps, was reading the stats upside down. I should have said I expected +20 *stamina* and +10 attack. In reality the set provides +20 stamina and +1 dexterity, so I was close...

Comment: Is that really supposed to be "Last Decent"? As in, this is the Last Decent Armor set available in the game?

Comment: @Raven Well spotted - it's actually a named set called **Last Descent** (made up of Last Descent Boots, etc), what a difference a single letter can make... *facepalm*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen the set bonus displayed in the abilities tab of the character screen, not exactly the place I would look for it but it was there.

Comment: Ah ha, *there* it is, thanks! What a rather arbitrary place for it to be...

Comment: @DMA I only noticed it by accident at some point